# C++ How Do I Export Address Table Hooking (EAT)?

Tags: windows, dll, assembly, portable-executable

How would I do Export Address Table (EAT) Hooking?

I'm able to do IAT (Import Address Table) hooking.

Can someone give me a example?

Thank You!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

EAT hooking follows a very similar method to IAT hooking, the major difference is a change in *where* you look, have a look at the PE File Exports section of the [Win32 PE format](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/ms809762.aspx).

A very simple (although in C) example can be found [here](http://www.unknowncheats.me/forum/c-and-c/50426-eat-hooking-dlls.html), just compile and disassemble if you really need it in assembly form.